# Neutron Flat networking with no dhcp

Tags: openstack, dhcp, flat

I would like to configure my openstack to use IP's from the same network as my physical server. I do not want to use dhcp or floating IP's.

```
neutron net-create --tenant-id TENANT-ID --shared sharednet1 --provider:network_type flat --provider:physical_network physnet1
neutron subnet-create sharednet1 10.68.10.0/24 --gateway-ip 10.68.10.11 --diable-dhcp
```

When create an instance , Nova should able to 'inject a ip' to instance.

1. Is that possiable ?
2. How to configure it?

Comment: I am also looking for answer, I have external `DHCP`. how VM will get IP from external DHCP?

Answer (score -2):

Please follow the basic installation guidehttp://docs.openstack.org/  for grizzly or havana in the networksection. 
You can use the static IPs of your physical servers by hard coding the static values in /etc/network/interface files so that when you create your router, it will use that IP